# Avoid rerendering noise texture on every frame of an animation

Tags: texturing, modifiers, displacement

I'm creating an animation in which I've used noise texture with displacement modifier for the bumps and roughness of the ground. It looks pretty good, but for some reason the texture on the ground is rendered for every frame, which results in a different ground texture for every frame.

How can I avoid rerendering the ground for every frame?

Here's a screenshot of the node editor and texture window:

[image: There's one texture coordinator node to the right]

Comment: are you using Blender Internel or Cycles Renderer?

Comment: @HenrikD Cycles Renderer

Comment: What is the scale of your Noisetexture? I suspect that it is too fine and float-prezision is rounding differently each time

Comment: @HenrikD I'm not using the node editor. I can't see anything like `scale` in the texture window

Comment: Wait what? If you make a Material in Cycles its always a Nodetree, just go into the Node Editor

Comment: @HenrikD There's nothing in the node editor related to the noise texture.

Comment: can you upload an image?

Comment: @HenrikD I've added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Oh thats what you meant with roughness... I thought you where clearly referring to the roughness in the Material Nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noise is a completly random Texture which is not necesserely equal for the same texture coordinate, each time you evaluate it. Use Clouds with very small size instead

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I'm quite new to blender.

Comment: In your Texturepanel you selected Noise. Just select Clouds instead